# Data bind enum properties to grid and display description

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, enums

This is a similar question to [How to bind a custom Enum description to a DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582105/how-to-bind-a-custom-enum-description-to-a-datagrid), but in my case I have multiple properties.

```
public enum ExpectationResult
{
    [Description("-")]
    NoExpectation,

    [Description("Passed")]
    Pass,

    [Description("FAILED")]
    Fail
}

public class TestResult
{
    public string TestDescription { get; set; }
    public ExpectationResult RequiredExpectationResult { get; set; }
    public ExpectationResult NonRequiredExpectationResult { get; set; }
}
```

I'm binding a BindingList<TestResult> to a WinForms DataGridView (actually a DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl, but a generic solution would be more widely applicable). I want the descriptions to appear rather than the enum names. How can I accomplish this? (There are no constraints on the class/enum/attributes; I can change them at will.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `TypeConverter` will usually do the job; here's some code that works for `DataGridView` - just add in your code to read the descriptions (via reflection etc - I've just used a string prefix for now to show the custom code working).

Note you would probably want to override `ConvertFrom` too. The converter can be specified at the type *or* the property level (in case you only want it to apply for some properties), and can also be applied at runtime if the enum isn't under your control.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpectationResultConverter))]
public enum ExpectationResult
{
    [Description("-")]
    NoExpectation,

    [Description("Passed")]
    Pass,

    [Description("FAILED")]
    Fail
}

class ExpectationResultConverter : EnumConverter
{
    public ExpectationResultConverter()
        : base(
            typeof(ExpectationResult))
    { }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value,
        System.Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            return "abc " + value.ToString(); // your code here
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}

public class TestResult
{
    public string TestDescription { get; set; }
    public ExpectationResult RequiredExpectationResult { get; set; }
    public ExpectationResult NonRequiredExpectationResult { get; set; }

    static void Main()
    {
        BindingList<TestResult> list = new BindingList<TestResult>();
        DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
        grid.DataSource = list;
        Form form = new Form();
        grid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        form.Controls.Add(grid);
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc! Combined with our EnumHelper (similar to the first part of rally25rs's answer), this elegant solution works beautifully - in a DataGridView. Unfortunately I found that the DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl does **not** detect the TypeConverter attribute. Sigh. But your answer is clearly correct.

Comment: ...and you pointed me in the right direction. I found that Developer Express does not plan to support this, and offers this workaround: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/CS2436.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how much this helps, but I use an extension method on Enum that looks like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the value of the description attribute attached to an enum value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="en"></param>
    /// <returns>The text from the System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute associated with the enumeration value.</returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// To use this, create an enum and mark its members with a [Description("My Descr")] attribute.
    /// Then when you call this extension method, you will receive "My Descr".
    /// </remarks>
    /// <example><code>
    /// enum MyEnum {
    ///     [Description("Some Descriptive Text")]
    ///     EnumVal1,
    ///
    ///     [Description("Some More Descriptive Text")]
    ///     EnumVal2
    /// }
    /// 
    /// static void Main(string[] args) {
    ///     Console.PrintLine( MyEnum.EnumVal1.GetDescription() );
    /// }
    /// </code>
    /// 
    /// This will result in the output "Some Descriptive Text".
    /// </example>
    public static string GetDescription(this Enum en)
    {
        var type = en.GetType();
        var memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());

        if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            var attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
                return ((DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description;
        }
        return en.ToString();
    }
```

You could use a custom property getter on your object to return the name:

```
public class TestResult
{
    public string TestDescription { get; set; }
    public ExpectationResult RequiredExpectationResult { get; set; }
    public ExpectationResult NonRequiredExpectationResult { get; set; }

    /* *** added these new property getters *** */
    public string RequiredExpectationResultDescr { get { return this.RequiredExpectationResult.GetDescription(); } }
    public string NonRequiredExpectationResultDescr { get { return this.NonRequiredExpectationResult.GetDescription(); } }
}
```

Then bind your grid to the "RequiredExpectationResultDescr" and "NonRequiredExpectationResultDescr" properties.

That might be a little over-complicated, but its the 1st thing I came up with :)

Comment: +1 for a good suggestion - thanks; we have an EnumHelper class already like your example, and another developer suggested the string properties, but I'm lazy. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the two other answers, I have put together a class that can generically convert between an arbitrary enum and a string using a Description attribute on each enum value.

This uses System.ComponentModel for the definition of DescriptionAttribute, and only supports conversion between T and String.

```
public class EnumDescriptionConverter<T> : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return (sourceType == typeof(T) || sourceType == typeof(string));
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return (destinationType == typeof(T) || destinationType == typeof(string));
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        Type typeFrom = context.Instance.GetType();

        if (typeFrom == typeof(string))
        {
            return (object)GetValue((string)context.Instance);
        }
        else if (typeFrom is T)
        {
            return (object)GetDescription((T)context.Instance);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Type converting from not supported: " + typeFrom.FullName);
        }
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        Type typeFrom = value.GetType();

        if (typeFrom == typeof(string) && destinationType == typeof(T))
        {
            return (object)GetValue((string)value);
        }
        else if (typeFrom == typeof(T) && destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            return (object)GetDescription((T)value);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Type converting from not supported: " + typeFrom.FullName);
        }
    }

    public string GetDescription(T en)
    {
        var type = en.GetType();
        var memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());

        if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
        {
            var attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
                return ((DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description;
        }
        return en.ToString();
    }

    public T GetValue(string description)
    {
        foreach (T val in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
        {
            string currDescription = GetDescription(val);
            if (currDescription == description)
            {
                return val;
            }
        }

        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("description", "Argument description must match a Description attribute on an enum value of " + typeof(T).FullName);
    }
}
```